# BOSH Director Installation fails on vSphere

Tags: cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

This is my first BOSH installation for PKS.
Environment:

- vSphere 6.5 with VCSA 6.5u2,
- OpsMgr 2.2 build 296
- bosh stemcell vsphere-ubuntu-trusty build 3586.25
- Using a flat 100.x network, no routing/firewall involved.

**Summary** - After deploying the OpsMgr OVF template, I'm configuring and installing BOSH Director.
However, it fails at "Waiting for Agent" in the dashboard.
A look at the 'current' log in the OpsMgr VM shows that it keeps trying to read settings from /dev/sr0, because the agent.json specifies settings Source as CDROM.
It cannot find any CDROM, so it fails.

A few questions:

1. How do I login to the VM that BOSH creates when I change the
   setting to "default BOSH password" for all VMs in Ops Mgr?
2. There is no bosh.yml under
   /var/tempest/workspaces/default/deployments.
       Some docs point to it. So I don't know what settings its applying. Is
       the location wrong?
3. Is there a way to change the stemcell used by the OpsMgr VM? Maybe I cantry 
   using the previous build?
4. How is the agent.json actually populated?
5. Any suggestions on troubleshooting this?

All logs/jsons below:

**the GUI dashboard log:**

```
===== 2018-07-30 08:20:52 UTC Running "/usr/local/bin/bosh --no-color --non-interactive --tty create-env /var/tempest/workspaces/default/deployments/bosh.yml"
Deployment manifest: '/var/tempest/workspaces/default/deployments/bosh.yml'
Deployment state: '/var/tempest/workspaces/default/deployments/bosh-state.json'

Started validating
Validating release 'bosh'... Finished (00:00:00)
Validating release 'bosh-vsphere-cpi'... Finished (00:00:00)
Validating release 'uaa'... Finished (00:00:00)
Validating release 'credhub'... Finished (00:00:01)
Validating release 'bosh-system-metrics-server'... Finished (00:00:01)
Validating release 'os-conf'... Finished (00:00:00)
Validating release 'backup-and-restore-sdk'... Finished (00:00:04)
Validating release 'bpm'... Finished (00:00:02)
Validating cpi release... Finished (00:00:00)
Validating deployment manifest... Finished (00:00:00)
Validating stemcell... Finished (00:00:14)
Finished validating (00:00:26)

Started installing CPI
Compiling package 'ruby-2.4-r4/0cdc60ed7fdb326e605479e9275346200af30a25'... Finished (00:00:00)
Compiling package 'vsphere_cpi/e1a84e5bd82eb1abfe9088a2d547e2cecf6cf315'... Finished (00:00:00)
Compiling package 'iso9660wrap/82cd03afdce1985db8c9d7dba5e5200bcc6b5aa8'... Finished (00:00:00)
Installing packages... Finished (00:00:15)
Rendering job templates... Finished (00:00:06)
Installing job 'vsphere_cpi'... Finished (00:00:00)
Finished installing CPI (00:00:23)

Starting registry... Finished (00:00:00)
Uploading stemcell 'bosh-vsphere-esxi-ubuntu-trusty-go_agent/3586.25'... Skipped [Stemcell already uploaded] (00:00:00)

Started deploying
Waiting for the agent on VM 'vm-87b3299a-a994-4544-8043-032ce89d685b'... Failed (00:00:11)
Deleting VM 'vm-87b3299a-a994-4544-8043-032ce89d685b'... Finished (00:00:10)
Creating VM for instance 'bosh/0' from stemcell 'sc-536fea79-cfa6-46a9-a53e-9de19505216f'... Finished (00:00:12)
Waiting for the agent on VM 'vm-fb90eee8-f3ac-45b7-95d3-4e8483c91a5c' to be ready... Failed (00:09:59)
Failed deploying (00:10:38)

Stopping registry... Finished (00:00:00)
Cleaning up rendered CPI jobs... Finished (00:00:00)

Deploying:
Creating instance 'bosh/0':
    Waiting until instance is ready:
    Post https://vcap:<redacted>@192.168.100.201:6868/agent: dial tcp 192.168.100.201:6868: connect: no route to host

Exit code 1
===== 2018-07-30 08:32:20 UTC Finished "/usr/local/bin/bosh --no-color --non-interactive --tty create-env /var/tempest/workspaces/default/deployments/bosh.yml"; Duration: 688s; Exit Status: 1
Exited with 1.
```

**The bosh_state.json**

```
ubuntu@opsmanager-2-2:~$ sudo cat /var/tempest/workspaces/default/deployments/bosh-state.json

{
    "director_id": "851f70ef-7c4b-4c65-73ed-d382ad3df1b7",
    "installation_id": "f29df8af-7141-4aff-5e52-2d109a84cd84",
    "current_vm_cid": "vm-87b3299a-a994-4544-8043-032ce89d685b",
    "current_stemcell_id": "dcca340c-d612-4098-7c90-479193fa9090",
    "current_disk_id": "",
    "current_release_ids": [],
    "current_manifest_sha": "",
    "disks": null,
    "stemcells": [
        {
            "id": "dcca340c-d612-4098-7c90-479193fa9090",
            "name": "bosh-vsphere-esxi-ubuntu-trusty-go_agent",
            "version": "3586.25",
            "cid": "sc-536fea79-cfa6-46a9-a53e-9de19505216f"
        }
    ],
    "releases": []
```

**The agent.json**

```
ubuntu@opsmanager-2-2:~$ sudo cat /var/vcap/bosh/agent.json
{
"Platform": {
    "Linux": {

    "DevicePathResolutionType": "scsi"
    }
},
"Infrastructure": {
    "Settings": {
    "Sources": [
        {
        "Type": "CDROM",
        "FileName": "env"
        }
    ]
    }
}
}
ubuntu@opsmanager-2-2:~$
```

**Finally, the current BOSH log**

```
/var/vcap/bosh/log/current


2018-07-30_08:42:22.69934 [main] 2018/07/30 08:42:22 DEBUG - Starting agent
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69936 [File System] 2018/07/30 08:42:22 DEBUG - Reading file /var/vcap/bosh/agent.json
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69937 [File System] 2018/07/30 08:42:22 DEBUG - Read content
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69937 ********************
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69938 {
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69938   "Platform": {
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69939     "Linux": {
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69939
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69939       "DevicePathResolutionType": "scsi"
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69939     }
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69939   },
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69939   "Infrastructure": {
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69940     "Settings": {
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69940       "Sources": [
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69940         {
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69940           "Type": "CDROM",
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69940           "FileName": "env"
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69940         }
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69941       ]
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69941     }
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69941   }
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69941 }
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69941
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69941 ********************
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69943 [File System] 2018/07/30 08:42:22 DEBUG - Reading file /var/vcap/bosh/etc/stemcell_version
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69944 [File System] 2018/07/30 08:42:22 DEBUG - Read content
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69944 ********************
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69944 3586.25
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69944 ********************
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69945 [File System] 2018/07/30 08:42:22 DEBUG - Reading file /var/vcap/bosh/etc/stemcell_git_sha1
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69946 [File System] 2018/07/30 08:42:22 DEBUG - Read content
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69946 ********************
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69946 dbbb73800373356315a4c16ee40d2db3189bf2db
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69947 ********************
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69948 [App] 2018/07/30 08:42:22 INFO - Running on stemcell version '3586.25' (git: dbbb73800373356315a4c16ee40d2db3189bf2db)
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69949 [File System] 2018/07/30 08:42:22 DEBUG - Checking if file exists /var/vcap/bosh/agent_state.json
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69950 [File System] 2018/07/30 08:42:22 DEBUG - Stat '/var/vcap/bosh/agent_state.json'
2018-07-30_08:42:22.69951 [Cmd Runner] 2018/07/30 08:42:22 DEBUG - Running command 'bosh-agent-rc'
2018-07-30_08:42:22.70116 [unlimitedRetryStrategy] 2018/07/30 08:42:22 DEBUG - Making attempt #0
2018-07-30_08:42:22.70117 [DelayedAuditLogger] 2018/07/30 08:42:22 DEBUG - Starting logging to syslog...
2018-07-30_08:42:22.70181 [Cmd Runner] 2018/07/30 08:42:22 DEBUG - Stdout:
2018-07-30_08:42:22.70182 [Cmd Runner] 2018/07/30 08:42:22 DEBUG - Stderr:
2018-07-30_08:42:22.70183 [Cmd Runner] 2018/07/30 08:42:22 DEBUG - Successful: true (0)
2018-07-30_08:42:22.70184 [settingsService] 2018/07/30 08:42:22 DEBUG - Loading settings from fetcher
2018-07-30_08:42:22.70185 [ConcreteUdevDevice] 2018/07/30 08:42:22 DEBUG - Kicking device, attempt 0 of 5
2018-07-30_08:42:22.70187 [ConcreteUdevDevice] 2018/07/30 08:42:22 DEBUG - readBytes from file: /dev/sr0
2018-07-30_08:42:23.20204 [ConcreteUdevDevice] 2018/07/30 08:42:23 DEBUG - Kicking device, attempt 1 of 5
2018-07-30_08:42:23.20206 [ConcreteUdevDevice] 2018/07/30 08:42:23 DEBUG - readBytes from file: /dev/sr0
2018-07-30_08:42:23.70217 [ConcreteUdevDevice] 2018/07/30 08:42:23 DEBUG - Kicking device, attempt 2 of 5
2018-07-30_08:42:23.70220 [ConcreteUdevDevice] 2018/07/30 08:42:23 DEBUG - readBytes from file: /dev/sr0
2018-07-30_08:42:24.20229 [ConcreteUdevDevice] 2018/07/30 08:42:24 DEBUG - Kicking device, attempt 3 of 5
2018-07-30_08:42:24.20294 [ConcreteUdevDevice] 2018/07/30 08:42:24 DEBUG - readBytes from file: /dev/sr0
2018-07-30_08:42:24.70249 [ConcreteUdevDevice] 2018/07/30 08:42:24 DEBUG - Kicking device, attempt 4 of 5
2018-07-30_08:42:24.70253 [ConcreteUdevDevice] 2018/07/30 08:42:24 DEBUG - readBytes from file: /dev/sr0
2018-07-30_08:42:25.20317 [ConcreteUdevDevice] 2018/07/30 08:42:25 DEBUG - readBytes from file: /dev/sr0
2018-07-30_08:42:25.20320 [ConcreteUdevDevice] 2018/07/30 08:42:25 ERROR - Failed to red byte from device: open /dev/sr0: no such file or directory
2018-07-30_08:42:25.20321 [ConcreteUdevDevice] 2018/07/30 08:42:25 DEBUG - Settling UdevDevice
2018-07-30_08:42:25.20322 [Cmd Runner] 2018/07/30 08:42:25 DEBUG - Running command 'udevadm settle'
2018-07-30_08:42:25.20458 [Cmd Runner] 2018/07/30 08:42:25 DEBUG - Stdout:
2018-07-30_08:42:25.20460 [Cmd Runner] 2018/07/30 08:42:25 DEBUG - Stderr:
2018-07-30_08:42:25.20461 [Cmd Runner] 2018/07/30 08:42:25 DEBUG - Successful: true (0)
2018-07-30_08:42:25.20462 [ConcreteUdevDevice] 2018/07/30 08:42:25 DEBUG - Ensuring Device Readable, Attempt 0 out of 5
2018-07-30_08:42:25.20463 [ConcreteUdevDevice] 2018/07/30 08:42:25 DEBUG - readBytes from file: /dev/sr0
2018-07-30_08:42:25.20464 [ConcreteUdevDevice] 2018/07/30 08:42:25 DEBUG - Ignorable error from readByte: open /dev/sr0: no such file or directory
2018-07-30_08:42:25.70473 [ConcreteUdevDevice] 2018/07/30 08:42:25 DEBUG - Ensuring Device Readable, Attempt 1 out of 5
2018-07-30_08:42:25.70476 [ConcreteUdevDevice] 2018/07/30 08:42:25 DEBUG - readBytes from file: /dev/sr0
2018-07-30_08:42:25.70477 [ConcreteUdevDevice] 2018/07/30 08:42:25 DEBUG - Ignorable error from readByte: open /dev/sr0: no such file or directory
2018-07-30_08:42:26.20492 [ConcreteUdevDevice] 2018/07/30 08:42:26 DEBUG - Ensuring Device Readable, Attempt 2 out of 5
2018-07-30_08:42:26.20496 [ConcreteUdevDevice] 2018/07/30 08:42:26 DEBUG - readBytes from file: /dev/sr0
2018-07-30_08:42:26.20497 [ConcreteUdevDevice] 2018/07/30 08:42:26 DEBUG - Ignorable error from readByte: open /dev/sr0: no such file or directory
2018-07-30_08:42:26.70509 [ConcreteUdevDevice] 2018/07/30 08:42:26 DEBUG - Ensuring Device Readable, Attempt 3 out of 5
2018-07-30_08:42:26.70512 [ConcreteUdevDevice] 2018/07/30 08:42:26 DEBUG - readBytes from file: /dev/sr0
2018-07-30_08:42:26.70513 [ConcreteUdevDevice] 2018/07/30 08:42:26 DEBUG - Ignorable error from readByte: open /dev/sr0: no such file or directory
2018-07-30_08:42:27.20530 [ConcreteUdevDevice] 2018/07/30 08:42:27 DEBUG - Ensuring Device Readable, Attempt 4 out of 5
2018-07-30_08:42:27.20533 [ConcreteUdevDevice] 2018/07/30 08:42:27 DEBUG - readBytes from file: /dev/sr0
2018-07-30_08:42:27.20534 [ConcreteUdevDevice] 2018/07/30 08:42:27 DEBUG - Ignorable error from readByte: open /dev/sr0: no such file or directory
2018-07-30_08:42:27.70554 [ConcreteUdevDevice] 2018/07/30 08:42:27 DEBUG - readBytes from file: /dev/sr0
2018-07-30_08:42:27.70557 [settingsService] 2018/07/30 08:42:27 ERROR - Failed loading settings via fetcher: Getting settings from all sources: Reading files from CDROM: Waiting for CDROM to be ready: Reading udev device: open /dev/sr0: no such file or directory
2018-07-30_08:42:27.70559 [settingsService] 2018/07/30 08:42:27 ERROR - Failed reading settings from file Opening file /var/vcap/bosh/settings.json: open /var/vcap/bosh/settings.json: no such file or directory
2018-07-30_08:42:27.70560 [main] 2018/07/30 08:42:27 ERROR - App setup Running bootstrap: Fetching settings: Invoking settings fetcher: Getting settings from all sources: Reading files from CDROM: Waiting for CDROM to be ready: Reading udev device: open /dev/sr0: no such file or directory
2018-07-30_08:42:27.70561 [main] 2018/07/30 08:42:27 ERROR - Agent exited with error: Running bootstrap: Fetching settings: Invoking settings fetcher: Getting settings from all sources: Reading files from CDROM: Waiting for CDROM to be ready: Reading udev device: open /dev/sr0: no such file or directory
2018-07-30_08:42:27.71258 [main] 2018/07/30 08:42:27 DEBUG - Starting agent


<and this whole block just keeps repeating>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I login to the VM that BOSH creates when I change the setting to "default BOSH password" for all VMs in Ops Mgr?

That's not a good idea. The [default password](https://bosh.io/docs/vm-config/#global) is well-known and you should almost always use randomly generated passwords. I'm not honestly sure why that's even an option. The only thing that comes to mind might be some extremely rare troubleshooting scenario.

That said, you can securely obtain the randomly generated password through Ops Manager, if you need to access the VM manually.  You can also securely access VMs via `bosh ssh`, and credentials are handled automatically.  Even for troubleshooting, you don't usually need that option.

> There is no bosh.yml under /var/tempest/workspaces/default/deployments. Some docs point to it. So I don't know what settings its applying. Is the location wrong?

The location is correct but the file contains sensitive information so Ops Manager deletes it immediately after it's done being used.

If you want to see the contents of the file, the easy way is to navigate to `https://ops-man-fqdn/debug/files` and you can see all of the configuration files, including your `bosh.yml`. The hard way is to watch the folder above while a deploy is going on and you'll see the file exist for a short period of time. You can make a copy during that window. The only advantage to the hard way is that you'll get the actual file, whereas the debug endpoint shows a file with sensitive info redacted.

> Is there a way to change the stemcell used by the OpsMgr VM? Maybe I cantry using the previous build?

I don't think this is an issue with the stemcell.  There are lots of people using those and not having this issue. If a larger issue like this were found with a stemcell, you would see a notice up on Pivotal Network and Pivotal would publish a new, fixed stemcell.

The problem also seems to be with how the VM is receiving it's initial bootstrap configuration. I'd suggest looking into that more before messing with the stemcells.  See below.

> How is the agent.json actually populated?

Believe it or not, for vSphere environments, that file is read from a fake CD-ROM that's attached to the VM.  There's not a lot documented, but it's mentioned briefly in the BOSH docs here.

https://bosh.io/docs/cpi-api-v1-method/create-vm/#agent-settings

> Any suggestions on troubleshooting this?

Look to understand why the CD-ROM can't be mounted. BOSH needs that to get it's bootstrap configuration, so you need to make that work.  If there is something in your vSphere environment that is preventing the CD-ROM from being mounted, you'll need to modify it to allow the CD-ROM to be mounted.

If there's nothing on the vSphere side, I think the next step would be to check the standard system logs under `/var/log` and `dmesg` output to see if there are any errors or clues as to why the CD-ROM can't be loaded/read from.

Lastly, try doing some manual tests to mount & read from the CD-ROM. Start by looking at one of the BOSH deployed VMs in the vSphere client, look at the hardware settings and make sure there is a CD-ROM attached. It should point to a file called `env.iso` in the same folder as the VM on your datastore. If that's attached & connected, start up the VM and try to mount the CD-ROM. You should be able to see the BOSH config files on that drive.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks - no luck though. This is BOSH director deployment, so no Director env yet to do ssh/get passwords etc i guess from other stemcells. I'm unable to login to the stemcell with vcap/c1oudc0w combination. It seems like the VM is starting without the CD/DVD drive connected. I manually connected it with the env.iso file in the datastore, but still no joy. Have to somehow login to the VM and check if /dev/sr0 is actually pointing to the CDROM device. Don't know if this is a factor, but the agent.json sets PathResolutionType to "scsi" whereas vmware CDROM is IDE.

Comment: So you tried to login with the vSphere Console using the default password combo & that didn't work? Did you try a couple times, just to rule out typos? The VM would get it's actual random password from the bootstrap file, so it should still have the default stemcell password.

Comment: Btw, how did you get the bosh agent log, if you're unable to login to the VM?

Comment: Hi Daniel,Yes tried a lot of times using the default username/password. The BOSH agent log is in the Ops Mgr VM at `/var/vcap/bosh/log/current`

Comment: OK, that's a different agent log file. Ops Manager doesn't run a bosh agent but it's built from a bosh stemcell which kind of explains why that exists. Ignore that file on Ops Manager, what you want is that same file but on the VM that is failing to start (the Director in your case). Unfortunately, it's hard to get without being able to login. I did a little investigation and pulled out the shadow file form the stemcell you're using. The `vcap` password there does not match the default from the docs, which explains why you can't login. I don't know the correct password to use though.

Comment: What I would suggest at this point is to force your stemcell to be deployed again and see if that helps. A coworker has occasionally see similar errors which had been caused by a corrupt stemcell in vSphere. To do that, delete `sc-536fea79-cfa6-46a9-a53e-9de19505216f` in the vSphere client, then set `current_stemcell_id` to `""` and `stemcells` to `[]` in `bosh_state.json`. Then Apply Changes in Ops Manager. If it works the line that says `Uploading stemcell...` in the output should *not* say "skipped", like it does above. You'll also see a new `sc-*` VM in vSphere.

Comment: Thanks. I've been at it for awhile now. I've redeployed Ops Mgr a couple of times, and I just delete the bosh_state.json to force a re-upload. I've also been trying the password from the installation.yml file (have to decrypt that file first) - but still no luck - could not log in. However, i just went through successfully on deploying BOSH director! No change in setup - just brute force keep repeating.

Comment: Weird, but glad you were able to get it to work. It's not normally such a challenge. Sorry I can't give you any more details about what might be causing these problems.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but maybe it will help someone, there's a firewall in vCenter that will prevent the agent from talking to the Bosh director.